# Prolog List predicate

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

Pretty new to PROLOG, and i'm having a problem with this list.

I need a predicate (`sublist(X,Y`) that is true if list `X` is a sublist of list `Y`. The sublist is the original list, in the same order, yet  some elements may have been removed. For instance, some sample user input is:

```
?- sublist([a,b],[a,e,b,d,s,e]).
Yes

?- sublist([a,b],[a,e,e,f]).
No

?- sublist([a,b],[b,a]).
No

?- sublist(X,[a,b,c]).
X = [] ;
X = [a] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, c] ;
X = [b] ;
X = [b, c] ;
X = [c] ;
No
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).
```

Got it! This works for both sub sequences and non sub-sequences in the list